# Get nth mat-row in cypress

Tags: angular-material, cypress

I have a mat-table where I need to get the 2nd, 3rd row, etc.
when I do:

```
cy.get('mat-table').find('mat-row').eq(1)
```

it will find the first row.
However, when I do:

```
cy.get('mat-table').find('mat-row').eq(2)
```

it's not finding the 2nd row.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cy.get('mat-table mat-row').eq(1)
```

If it is not helping, can you add the error which you are getting and may be the html layout?

Also [according to this](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax), your first statement should be getting second element as indexing starts from 0